# jquery Counter is not starting from 0 to the target number

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, counter, setinterval

Trying to create counter which starts from 0 and go up to target value. I tried to Use setInterval but it didn't work, As I do not have much clear idea of it I have referred certain tutorial also still not able to work my code. If someone can help me by correcting my code would be great for me.
Thank You In Advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tts-counter .tts-counter-item .tts-number').each(function() {
        var counterValue = $(this).data('counter');
        var finalValue = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= counterValue; i++) {
            $(this).text(finalValue);
            finalValue++;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And where is problem? This code should show you the highest number. There is no interval between changes, so all of them are done immediatelly.

Comment: I want it to start from 0 to the target value. But it directly shows me the targeted value.

Comment: Sure, read my comment once again and carefully. How your script should know if you want to change the value in 100ms or 2 minutes? Use setInterval. Your loop do exactly what you want, with almost zero interval between every step.

Comment: okay Will try it thank you. should I add setInterval inside the loop?

Comment: Open any JS tutorial, find there `setTimeout` and think about it. My last comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking and referring to many articles related to counters I found this solution.

```
$('.tts-number').each(function() {
                $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                    Counter: $(this).text()
                }, {
                    duration: 4000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function(now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                    }
                });
            });
```